# Defining distance in minutes from motorway in QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing

First I have downloaded a shapefile with Austria's transport system.Then I created a layer which now only consists of Austria's motorways. I would like to create a sort of buffer around the motorway (drive time isochrone). The buffer is meant to be in a distance of 10 minutes around the motorway. In the screenshot below one can see that the max speed for each road is given. I am not sure if there is still need for other Information besides the max speed. Is there a chance of creating the things i have in my mind with only this Information given?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS SE. You also could use OSM Tools Plugin to do this. Here is a link for further information http://www.digital-geography.com/short-announcement-new-osm-routing-plugin-for-qgis-osm-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As far as I understand I can find the fastest or shortest route using OSM Tools using two spots. I already have the track of the road ("motorway"). I also read about pgRouting but seems like that's a similar thing. i know that i can create a simple buffer with fixed distance, but that won't consider the speed on the roads. 
The file "Verkehrsnetz Ö" contains all streets and their max allowed speed. So I thought there is maybe a way I can use the layer instead of every single object.

Comment: You can also use a layer with more spots to find shortest routes --> from A to B,C,D.. also, the results from osm tools have speeds included